# How to create a floating div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, floating

When the mouse is over an element A of a certain class , another floating div B, which contains a link, should appear. B should disappear as soon as the mouse has left A and B.

How can I do this with jQuery?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2gFb/2/)

```
var container = $('#container');
var area = $('.area'); // this is A
var position = area.offset();

var floating = $("<div />", {
        css : { "position"  :   "absolute",
                "top"       :   position.top - 30,
                "left"      :   position.left + 20,
                "border"    :   "1px solid #000",
                "padding"   :   "5px",
                "display"   :   "none",
                "z-index"   :   "100",
                "background-color"  :   "#F00"
        }
    })
        .text('Hello World'); // this is B

    container.css('position', 'relative');
    container.append(floating);

    function show() {
        floating.show();
    }

    function hide() {
        floating.hide();
    }

    area.on('mouseenter', show);
    area.on('mouseleave', hide);
    floating.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
        console.log("floating: mouseenter");
        area.off('mouseenter', show);
        area.off('mouseleave', hide);
    });
    floating.on('mouseleave', function(event) {
        console.log("floating: mouseleave");
        area.on('mouseenter', show);
        area.on('mouseleave', hide);
    });
```

My problem is that evertime the mouse enters B, B disappears already. I need to do this with jQuery, not only CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have to put the floating div in the jQuery. This is probably how I would achieve something similar to what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/A2gFb/6/

Just put the hidden float in the HTML,

```
<div class="area">luptatum zzril
    <div class="fixed">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

with proper CSS set.

```
.area {
    position: relative;
    color: #0F0;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* you may want to set the width/height here as well*/
}

.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100;  /* Thanks Diego for pointing out the typo here */
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

And the jQuery would be as simple as this:

```
$(".area").mouseenter( function() {
    $(".fixed").show();
});

$(".area").mouseleave( function() {
    $(".fixed").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The major problem you are having is that the mouseleave event for your green text is firing before the mouseenter for your floating div. To fix this I made a variable to track the mouse being in the float and used a setTimeout in the hide() function to check for this variable after 100 ms. You could probably go lower if you were worried about the delay. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/f8tan/1/)

At the top of the javascript:

```
var inFloat = false;
```

The hide() function becomes:

```
function hide() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!inFloat)
            floating.hide();
    },100);
}
```

And your floating mouse events become:

```
floating.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    inFloat = true;
});
floating.on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    inFloat = false;
    floating.hide();
});
```

You still have the issue that the floating div has a fixed position that isn't related to the mouse position, so it may be awkward to hover over the link and then move to floating div at times.

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
floating.on('mouseenter', show);
floating.on('mouseleave', hide);
```

it works on jsFiddle.

By the way, I suggest you to not use "show" and "hide" as function name since they already exist in jQuery. showTooltip and hideTooltip can be good names.